# Is it possible to check for a possible conversion in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typing

In JavaScript, variables are loosely typed, so the number `5` and the string `"5"` may both be treated as a number by several operators. However, is there a generic way to find out JavaScripts conversion abilites in at tunrime, or is it just the overloading of operators for several types that make the loose typing possible?

For example, given a variable `a` and a string containing a type name `type_canditate`, is there any way to ask JavaScript, if `a` may convert to `type_candidate` in a feasable manner, in contrast to the hard typing operators like `instanceof`? For example, `"5" instanceof Number` evaluates false, while `Math.sin("5")` is perfectly feasable. For numbers, one can obviuosly check if `parseFloat(some_number)` evaluates to `NaN`, but this is a special case for numbers.

So, is there any generic way of naming types, and check if some variable may convert to a given type in a useful manner?

Comment: There's no facility expressly for that purpose, but you can always *attempt* a conversion to a type from any other type to see what you get.

Comment: Also, `parseFloat()` is *not* a good way to check for convertability. The `Number()` constructor is safer.

Comment: What are the benefits of `Number` over `parseFloat`?

Comment: Try in your browser console `parseFloat("23skidoo");`

Comment: Ok, but try `Number('')`, it evaluates to 0. So both of these conversions do not discern numbers from non-numbers. What a mess...

Comment: No, `Number("23skidoo")` returns `NaN` - don't call it with `new`, just use it as a function.

Comment: Actually, you're right in the way that `Math.sin` for example seems to behave like `Number`. But regarding the `+` operator, we still cannot assume that `Number(a)` evaluating to `NaN` does mean we can expect a number if converted to string. Also `Number('a')==NaN` evaluates false, why is this?

Comment: @Pointy: I don't questioned  `Number("23skidoo")` returning `NaN`, I just said that `Number('')` is not returning `NaN`, but `0`, while `''` is definetely not a number by human means.

Comment: Ah, yes that's true. The empty string is treated as zero by the standard conversion rules (which is pretty silly but that's the way the language is specified).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three primitive data types in JavaScript: string, number and boolean.

Anything can be converted to a string or boolean:

- All objects convert to `true` (except `null`, which becomes `false` - I only mention it here because `typeof null` gives `object`)
- All objects have a built-in `toString` method which is called when converting to a string.
- Converting a number to a string is done by giving the string representation of the number (ie. `5` becomes `"5"`)
- Numbers convert to boolean `true`, unless it's `0` which becomes `false`.

Converting to a number is a little trickier, but technically possible. If it can find a valid number, then it becomes that number. Otherwise, it becomes `NaN`.

So basically... *any* type can become *any other type* through casting in this way. The only time you have anything resembling an "error condition" is `NaN`.

Comment: Objects are converted to numbers via the `valueOf()` function, which is basically the number analogue of `toString()`.

Comment: Just asked another question about checking for numbers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22100243/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-a-number-in-javascript