# How to convert a string to 0 if it isn't containing any digit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have this inputs:

```
var str1 = "21";
var str2 = "1.";
var str3 = "5. test"
var str4 = "- something";
```

I want this outputs:

```
// 21
// 1
// 5
// 0
```

---

- **First** case doesn't need to convert.
- **Second** case need to use `Number();`.
- **Third** case using `.replace(/(\d)/g, "$1");`.
- But how can I do **fourth** case? Actually I want to replace a string with `0` if it isn't containing number.

---

My question seems easy, but that's 30min which I'm thinking about it and still I couldn't solve it.

Comment: check if first element is number ... if not than assign 0 to it

Comment: @YoYo It returns `NaN`

Comment: check for first element for str4 only because 1. will also return NaN ,,,right

Comment: @YoYo No, [`Number("1.");`](https://jsfiddle.net/hunyLezf/) returns `1`.

Comment: [Please try this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778020/check-whether-an-input-string-contains-number) [Or this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22100243/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-a-number-in-javascript)

Comment: @Yingy Thank you ... I wonder, How did you able to write a comment under my question (because you have just 1 rep)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) and [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

```js
var str1 = "21";
var str2 = "1.";
var str3 = "5. test"
var str4 = "- something";

console.log(isNaN(parseInt(str1)) ? 0 : parseInt(str1));
console.log(isNaN(parseInt(str2)) ? 0 : parseInt(str2));
console.log(isNaN(parseInt(str3)) ? 0 : parseInt(str3));
console.log(isNaN(parseInt(str4)) ? 0 : parseInt(str4));
```

Comment: how can he use this ... since `1.` will also reurn NaN ,,, so should he assign 0 to it ????

Answer (score 2):

you can say if the number(yourString) = NaN then print 0

Comment: `Number("5. test")` will also result in NaN.

Comment: in this case I recommend using charAt(0) to check if it has an integer at the beginning or not. if it did, you can check the next char (charAt(1)) until it returns something rather than a number or it ends. you can check if the returned char is a number or not by checking it's aasci code

Answer (score 1):

```
   var patt = /([0-9]+)/,
       match = patt.exec(str);
   if (!match) 
        str = 0;
   else
       str = match[1];
```

This will match first number from your string.

Comment: I want if that condition is `true`, then returns such a number ...!

Comment: This code will print 0 if there is no number in your string. If I get your question.

Comment: Ok I got the whole point. You want to test all the conditions. I am adding an edit.

Comment: now try the edit. If you have to match more than one numbers in your string, you can run a loop. This one will bring first matched number from your string or will store 0 if there is no number in string.

Comment: Good `:-)`. Now it is a complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
var str4 = "- something"; 
str4 = ( str4.match(/\d+/g)) ? str4 : 0;
```